# How to change temporal tooltip in altair to UTC?

Tags: python, timezone, altair

pandas.datafame in UTC, x-axis can be plotted in utc, tooltip in local time

hey folks,
I am trying to plot the following diagram. A timeline plot with meteorological data. All data is in UTC in a pandas dataframe.
I convert the X-axis to UTC like so:
`x = alt.X('time', type="temporal", scale=alt.Scale(type="utc"), axis=alt.Axis(title='Time in UTC', format='%H:%m', tickSize=0))`

The same does not work for the tooltip though:
`tooltip.append(alt.Tooltip('time:T', format='%H:%M', scale=alt.Scale(type="utc"))`

Even though it works when I do it in the vega-lite editor!

I get the following error:
.../python3.9/site-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py", line 340, in to_dict
raise SchemaValidationError(self, err)
altair.utils.schemapi.SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

```
    altair.vegalite.v4.schema.channels.OpacityValue, validating 'additionalProperties'

    Additional properties are not allowed ('selection' was unexpected)
```

Here is the plot in [vega-lite editor:](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

I solved the issue with a dirty trick:
I change the dict posteriorly and add the necessary lines in the vega-lite dict...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the full code you tried in Altair for this? As well as a sample of the data as text to reproduce the issue?